# Testing Spring JDBC with JMockit with JUnit4

Tags: java, spring, junit4, jmockit

I am testing a Spring JDBC class using the JMockit.
The following is the test class:

public class DAOImplTest {

```
@Tested
DAOImpl daoImpl;

@Mocked
JdbcTemplate mockJdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{
    daoImpl = new DAOImpl();
    daoImpl.setJdbcTempate(mockJdbcTemplate);
}

@Test
public void testGetSomeString() throws Exception{
    final String expectedO = "7c82facc";
    final String expectedG = "one";

    new Expectations() {{
        mockJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SSODAOImpl.GET_IDS, String.class, expectedO);
        result = expectedG;
    }};

    DAOImpl daoImpl = new DAOImpl();
    String actual = daoImpl.getSomeString(expectedO);
    assertEquals(expected, actualG);
}
```

}

The class is throwing NullPointer Exception on line `String actual = daoImpl.getSomeString(expectedO)`

What's the reason for getting the null pointer exception at the very point?

The following is the DAOImpl class method:

```
public String getSomeString(String or) {
DAORowMapper rowMapper = new DAORowMapper();
            String g = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_IDS, rowMapper, orgIds);
            return g;
}
```

Here is the stack trace while running the JUnit 4 Test. Again the NullPointer exception is when running the Junit4 Test Case

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.DAOImpl.getSomeString(DAOImpl.java:31)
    at comDAOImplTest.testGetSomeString(DAOImplTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that within `getSomeString()` the `jdbcTemplate` field is `null`.  This is because while you set this field on the `daoImpl` field in the `setup()` method, you are not using the `daoImpl` field....you are shadowing the field with a local variable here:

```
DAOImpl daoImpl = new DAOImpl();
```

This local variable doesn't have the `jdbcTemplate` field set to the mock object.  Remove that line and I'm thinking it will work.

Comment: If I remove DAOImpl daoImpl = new DAOImpl(); i get the following error!

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected invocation of:
Object org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#queryForObject(String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper, Object[])
on instance: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@5ff06dc3

removing DAOImpl daoImpl = new DAOImpl(); gets that error

Comment: Jeff's answer is correct. The "unexpected invocation" you get when calling on the `@Tested daoImpl` object happens simply because the strict expectation recorded on `mockJdbcTemplate` was not matched; instead, an (unexpected) invocation with different arguments was detected. So, you probably need to adjust the recorded expectation. You might also prefer to use non-strict expectations instead (ie, `new NonStrictExpectations() {{ ... }}`.

Comment: He's correct. The way it worked for me was by deleting the instances of daoImpl. Getting ride of @Before which removes the new Instances.